# Pass textarea value from WYSIWYG CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, textarea, wysiwyg

I'm trying to pass the input I made in a WYSIWYG editor (CK Editor) to JQuery. Currently it's blank no matter what I input.

HTML:

```
<textarea type='text' class="ckeditor reply"  name='reply'></textarea>
<button type="button" STYLE="align: right;" class="btn btn-info reply_button yGreenButton">Submit Reply</button>
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(function()
{
    $('.reply_button').click(function(){

        var reply=$(this).siblings('.reply').val();

    });
});
</script>
```

The textarea shows up as CKeditor. The current value alerted from the clicking the reply_button is blank, no matter what I put in the CKeditor textarea. How to get the actual content I input to be alerted?

Advice is hugely appreciated.

Best,

Answer (score 2):

It's a CKEditor, you have to use their API:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( '.ckeditor' );
editor.getData();
```

The API docs can be found [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor).

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it's not working. The reason is that I actually used the class="ckeditor" to replace the textarea, and therefore the value cannot be returned by editor.getData(); It shows "undefined" error

Answer (score 1):

You've got two options - you can use CKEditor API directly, or CKEditor adapter for jQuery.

To use CKEditor API directly, you need the editor instance. You can get it from the [`CKEDITOR.instances`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-property-instances) object using `id` or `name` of related `textarea` or automatically generated name ('editor1', 'editor2', etc). In your case:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.reply;
var val = editor.getData();
```

To use jQuery adapter, you need to load `adapters/jquery.js` file after `ckeditor.js` and then you can retrieve value easily:

```
var val = $( '.ckeditor' ).val();
```

Just like you would use normal `textarea`. Read more in the [jQuery adapter guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery) and check the [CKEditor with jQuery sample](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/jquery.html).